# Does the desktop version have a limitation on TCP connection number?

Tags: networking

We have a server application in JAVA, these days when the TCP connection number is more than 1000, I get the error message "too many open files",  although I have increased the number of file descriptors available via `ulimit` to 10240, this error still occurs with less than 1500 connections.

I am using the Ubuntu desktop version, does the desktop version have a limit on the number of TCP connections?

Comment: Are you closing your sockets correctly? You shouldn't receive this unless you're having a lot of simulataneous connections...